# How do I add Scanner user inputs of varying length to an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I am trying to build an ArrayList of integers that is built through Scanner. The user must input between 5 and 10 integers for the ArrayList to be valid, but the actual number of inputs will be unknown at the time the program is run.

How do I build the program so that it only runs as long as the user inputs 5,6,7,8,9, or 10 integers?

The user is supposed to input all integers on a single line, but the code I tried below cuts it off after the 5th integer, even if there are more after it

```
public static ArrayList arrayListBuilder() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList();
    System.out.println("Enter 5-10 ints");
    while (input.hasNextInt()) {
        integerList.add(input.nextInt());
        if (integerList.size() > 4 && integerList.size() < 9) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return integerList;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Well, of course, because `integerList.size() > 4`. Also, `integerList.size() < 9` is redundant.

Comment: why `new ArrayList();` instead of new ArrayList<>();

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your if statement. It looks like you are trying to ensure that the user's input has more than 4 ints and less than 9 ints. However, what is happening in practice is that you are reading through the user's input one int at a time and once your array of user input is larger than 4, you stop. There are a few things you could try if you want to keep it in roughly the same format. Move the check for the lower bound outside of the while loop so that the program will populate your array list and then check if it is large enough. If it is not large enough, loop back up. Then inside of the while loop keep the check for the upper bound. I believe this will accomplish what you are trying to do. I have attached sample code that might help.

```
    public static ArrayList arrayListBuilder() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList();
        while (true){
            integerList.clear();
            System.out.println("Enter 5-10 ints");
            Boolean rightSize = true;
            while (input.hasNextInt()) {
                integerList.add(input.nextInt());
                if (integerList.size() > 9) {
                    rightSize = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (integerList.size() < 5){
                rightSize = false;
            }
            if (rightSize){
                break;
            }
        }
        return integerList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea of the check, but don't have it in the right position. If it is inside the loop, the check will be run every single time any input is given. That means that when the list receives the 5th element, the check will return true and break from the loop. Instead, you should read as many inputs you can (or have some sort of maximum, like 10) and perform the check afterwards. It might look something like this:

```java
public static ArrayList arrayListBuilder() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList();
    System.out.println("Enter 5-10 ints");
    while (input.hasNextInt()) {
        integerList.add(input.nextInt());
        if (integerList.size() > 10)
            break;
    }
    if (!(integerList.size() >= 5 && integerList.size() <= 10)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Received too many integers");
    }
    return integerList;
}
```

This will, rather than check the size every iteration of the loop, check if the size of the list is outside of the bounds afterwards, when the scanner has no more integers to give, or has more than the maximum (being the new check if the size is greater than 10, which can be omitted). Once the loop is finished, the new check is performed, and if there are more or less than the desired number, it will throw an error.

If you would prefer it to not throw an error, you could do a single check to see if it is above or below the desired range, but doing something like this:

```java
if (integer.size() > 10) {
    // Clamp the size of the list to the correct length, being 10
} else if (integer.size() < 5) {
    // Ask for more numbers, or throw an error
}
```

That would replace the other check outside of the loop, and would allow for more customization in the handling of the sizes.

What that new check does is checks if the size is larger than the bigger side of the range, and the `else if` check is if the size is smaller than the small side of the range. In total, it is just separating the previous check into two if statements to allow you to have the ability to clamp, or ask for more integers. That being said, if it is inside of the range, it will just pass through, and return the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build the list as long as the user enters the 5,6,7,8,9, or 10 and you do not know the actual size of the valid input, here is something I came up with:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayListBuilder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        arrayListBuilder();
    }

    public static List<Integer> arrayListBuilder() {
        List<Integer> referenceList = Arrays.asList(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

        List<Integer> inputList = new ArrayList<>();
        getUserInput(referenceList, inputList);

        System.out.println(inputList);
        return inputList;

    }

    private static void getUserInput(List<Integer> referenceList, List<Integer> inputList) {
        System.out.println("Enter 5-10 ints");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userInput = input.nextInt();
        if (referenceList.contains(userInput)) {
            inputList.add(userInput);
            getUserInput(referenceList, inputList);
        } 
    }

}
```